# Как вычесть 1 час в Carbon?

Tags: laravel, laravel5, carbon

Как вычесть 1 час в Carbon laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$yorDate->subHour();`

Манипуляции с временем и датой на любой [вкус и цвет](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

Если просто нужно добавить час времени, то:

```
$date = Carbon::parse('2018-04-04 22:34:56')->addHour();
```

Если нужно сравнить две даты на этот час:

```
$someTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '18:15:10'); // добавляем время

$someTime1 = $someTime->addHours(10)->addMinutes(15)->toTimeString();// время для сравнения

echo $someTime->diffInHours($someTime1); // разница
```